# Applying global CSS to injected HTML (v-html)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to inject HTML from my database using Vue. I'm able to successfully inject HTML however the problem I'm having is my framework stylesheet (Vuetify) isn't being applied.
It's applied to the rest of the page just not the injected HTML.

How can I get the injected HTML to use my Vuetify CSS?

Also, the images in my HTML aren't rendered either although I can see them when inspecting the HTML.

```
<div v-html="post.format"></div>
```

Output HTML:

```
<div>
  <v-container grid-list-md="" text-xs-center="">
    <v-layout row="" wrap="">
      <v-flex xs12="" md12="" lg6="">
        <p class="text-lg-left">Post description text</p>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12="" md12="" lg6="">
        <v-img class="center" style="max-width:250px" src="/img/1.jpg"></v-img>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

  </v-container>

  <v-container grid-list-md="" text-xs-center="">
    <v-layout row="" wrap="">
      <v-flex xs12="" md12="" lg6="">
        <v-img width="250px" class="center" src="/img/2.jpg">
        </v-img>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12="" md12="" lg6="">
        <p class="text-lg-left">More post description text</p>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

Comment: could you show the post.format html

Comment: Updated it with the post.format HTML. Between the <div> tags is the HTML that is stored in my database. It looks fine when inspecting element on my page. But my Vuetify css isn't being applied only on this part of the page.

Also the VueJS v html tags don't render properly. For example my <v-img< isn't being displayed and only displays when replacing with <img>

Comment: That's because Vue doesn't process `v-html`'s output. You can read up on that [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html).

Comment: Is there a way I can insert HTML and have it processed by Vue?

Comment: I don't think that's possible unfortunately. What are you trying to achieve by injecting markup like that if I may ask. Maybe there's a better way of going about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I'm trying to store a unique post description in my database and have it output for each page/post. Similar to Wordpress where you can save HTML to a post and have it output along with the framework CSS.

Comment: I think the easiest way to accomplish that is to use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). You can decide which component gets rendered based on the post type which you fetch from the database.

Comment: The title is misleading, it indicates that problem is applying CSS, but instead problem seems to be rendering vuetify components from a string (or any vue components whatsoever).

Answer (score 0):

As @Husam mentioned, Vue won't allow you to do this. It's ultimately for the best, and even v-html should be used with caution. Regarding the css, [from the Vue.js site](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html):

> In single-file components, scoped styles will not apply to content
> inside v-html, because that HTML is not processed by Vue’s template
> compiler. If you want to target v-html content with scoped CSS, you
> can instead use CSS modules or an additional, global  element
> with a manual scoping strategy such as BEM.

As for a better way, judging from the look of your output, I'd suggest storing your straight-text data in a database/collection, and making a component template for this type of post. In your database/collection, you could store the title, description, imageURL, and perhaps a componentType. Then, when rendering, you could render the particular component type from what was stored in the db.

That would be cleaner, safer, and perhaps easier to maintain. [I created a sample of what I'm talking about here on CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/6j7vx006o3) The sandbox is preventing the images from loading but it's there. I split your output into two different components to see also.

[image: Edit Vue Template]